# How to schedule executing method for certain time during runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, schedule

Lets say I have some rest api where arguments are time when to execute method and second argument is name of the method in class. What is the best way for invoking call of this method in certain time (just once) in spring-boot application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, enable scheduling in your spring-boot application:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {
// ...
```

Then, inject the `TaskScheduler` bean and schedule the task programmatically every time the user invokes the REST method:

```java
public class MyScheduler {

    @Autowired
    private TaskScheduler scheduler;

    public void scheduleNewCall(Date dateTime) {
        scheduler.schedule(this::scheduledMethod, dateTime);
    }

    public void scheduledMethod() {
    // method that you wish to run
    }

}
```

However, you should also think about limiting the amount of calls to this method, otherwise the malicious user could schedule a lot of tasks and overflow the task pool.

Comment: nice thx for the example. I was curious if there is something better then just taskScheduler. And yea there is also some authentication so just few admins can plan task